# JQuery If Statement: If Price = 0, Display Message

Tags: jquery, magento2

Working on a file that displays/overlays pricing for Magento 2.3.3 and I have the following JQuery statement:

```
 if(price != 0){
  $('#product-price-'+product_id+' .price').html(price);      
  }
```

I want to change that so that if the price = 0, it displays a message to call for a quote.  I have tried the following with no luck. It still displays all 0 prices.

```
  if(price != 0){
   alert('Call For Quote');      
  }
```

Here is the full script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["jquery","mage/loader"],function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {

            var customurl = "<?php echo $this->getUrl() . 'customer/index/price'?>";
            var productId = "<?php echo $productId; ?>";
            var loaderImg = "<?= $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif') ?>";
            var loaderHtml = '<div id="price-panel-'+productId+'"  data-role="pannel" class="price-panel" style="position: absolute;"><div data-role="loader" class="loading-mask" style="position: relative;"><div class="loader"><img style="position: relative;" src="'+loaderImg+'" alt="loading" width="30px"></div></div>';

            $('[data-role=priceBox]').hide();
            $('#product-price-'+productId+' .price').hide();
            $('[data-product-id='+productId+']').before(loaderHtml);
            $("#price-panel-"+productId+ " .loader").show();

            $.ajax({
                url: customurl,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    productId: productId,
                },
                complete: function(response) {


                    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(response.responseJSON)) {

                        product_id = value.productId;
                        price = value.price;
                        qty = value.qty;                             
                       /* product_id = response.responseJSON.productId;
                        price = response.responseJSON.price;
                        qty = response.responseJSON.qty;*/

                        if(product_id){
                            $('[data-role=priceBox]').show(); 
                            loaderClass = "div.price-panel-"+product_id;
                            $("#price-panel-"+product_id).hide();   


                            $('#product-price-'+product_id+' .price').show();

                            if (price != 0) {
                                $('#product-price-' + product_id + ' .price').html(price);
                            } else {
                                alert("Call for quote");
                                }


                           /* if(qty != 0){
                                $('#product-available-qty-'+product_id).html('Available: '+qty); 
                            }*/
                            console.log(price);    
                        }
                    }                        

                },
                error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('Error happens. Try again.');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You may just need to change `price != 0` to `price === 0` if I'm reading this correctly..

Comment: Changed. Price is still displaying as $0.

Comment: Is the '$' included in the value of your price variable?

Comment: The price shows up on the front end as $0.00. I have added the full script above.

Comment: What does `console.log(typeof price)` show?

Comment: Does `price` begin with `$`?

Comment: No, the code has not implemented $

Comment: is it a string and not a number?

Comment: Could very well be. I was thinking this was going to be easy...

Answer (score 0):

Put the alert in the `else` block.

```
if (price != 0) {
  $('#product-price-' + product_id + ' .price').html(price);
} else {
  alert("Call for quote");
}
```

Comment: Added and still no luck. I must not be editing the right string for it to replace the pricing.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about Magento.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the `!==` operator? as it compares the value and also checks the type.

e.g. `price !== 0`